# jquery redirect to another link when clicking a button

Tags: jquery, redirect, hyperlink

I have two buttons: remove and update. Those buttons when they are clicked load to http://homepage/?removed_item=1 or http://homepage/cart.

So what I want is just to redirect to homepage.
Is that possible with jquery ?..

their classes are: .remove and .update

EDIT: after the button has been clicked and has done it's process, it will redirect

Comment: Do you mean after the button has been clicked and has done it's process, it will redirect. Or do you just want them to go straight to the homepage regardless?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: @Stewartside yes, thank you.. after the button has been clicked and has done it's process, it will redirect, i edit my original post..

Comment: Then that is done on the actual pages themselves and not on the click events. You'll need to provide the code for the processes that it runs on the two pages

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$(".remove").click(function() {
  window.location = "http://homepage/";
});

$(".update").click(function() {
  window.location = "http://homepage/";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

> **event.preventDefault()** : If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

You should use JQuery method **[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent default `href` and then redirect to homepage.

**HTML :**

```
<a href='http://homepage/cart' class='update'>Update</a>
<a href='http://homepage/?removed_item=1' class='remove'>Remove</a>
```

**JS :**

```
$(".update, .remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace("http://homepage/");
});
```

If you want to redirect after finishing process, you have to use JQuery function **[$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**.

**JS :**

```
$(".update, .remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.get($(this).attr('href'),function(result){
        window.location.replace("http://homepage/");        
    })
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: event.preventDefault() is not a jQuery method

Comment: [jQuery event.preventDefault() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
To be clear: it's also an method of the "jquery event arg"!

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't do the remove and update first and the redirect.

Is there another way ?

I edit my original post too, to explain more!

Comment: To summarize the event discussion in the comments. "jQuery's event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object."[jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)